# How to generate all unique combinations of a list of words?

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of words like:

```
List={"word1", "word2", "word3", ....}
```

How can i generate a "two word length" list of 
all unique combination of these words?

For example, if above list contains only three 
words then the output might be like:

```
word1 word2
word1 word3
word2 word1
word2 word4
word3 word1
word3 word2
```

Also, note that `"word1 word2"` is not 
same as `"word2 word1"`.

I know a simplest solution like this:

```
for i=1 to N
  for j=1 to N
    if(i!=j) then
      print List[i]+" "+List[j]
```

But this has O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity. So, what is 
the best algorithm with least worst case 
complexity for achieving the same.

Comment: How do you expect to do better than O(n²) when the output itself is n²??

Answer (score 8):

The output of the algorithm contains `O(n^2)` elements. Since every output element needs to be attended to, you can't hope to achieve better than `O(n^2)` time complexity.